# How to handle relational data in C# without the use of classes

Tags: c#

How to store/handle relational data in C# eg. many to many relationship

Please note a class for each entitiy is NOT an option here, though that the only solution I can think about righ now.

XML is not an option either.

What data structure will handle relational data?

Can I use Jagged array or list, if so how?

Note: the data is not stored in a database but will be dynamically created.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [System.Data.DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) and its related classes.  It's usage is usually frowned upon because best practices often suggest a class hierarchy to represent the data.  But if it's relational data in memory you want, this is a rich set of classes that the .Net Framework provides.  You can fill it dynamically, too, the DataSet does not have to be populated through ADO.Net.

Comment: I should mention too that in Visual Studio you can design a strongly-typed DataSet as well.  You can define columns and Visual Studio will generate classes derived from DataSet & DataTable that expose your tables and columns in a strongly-typed way.

Comment: If my answer is the most helpful to you, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Thanks!